# GeoServer accidentally sat up a proxy base URL from Admin GUI > Global settings > proxy_base url

Tags: geoserver, proxy

Sorry to say I sat up a DNS proxy base URL in GeoServers Global settings that is not going to be anymore. The DNS will probably be another one in time.

Anyway after that setting I can't log on with the admin interface to correct/erase that setting. At logon it just forward to that DNS and a "status 404 not found".

I figured I could just change that back in the web.xml file, but when looking in that file it does not seem to have changed at all. The sentence in the web.xml is commented out and the file is not changed since installation.

Is there anything else I can do to undo the setting in the Admin interface I did? Some other file or so? or do I have to redo the whole GeoServer installation?

The server is using Tomcat if that helps.

```
<!-- <context-param>
<param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
<param-value>http://82.58.146.45/geoserver</param-value>
</context-param>
-->
```

Comment: just type the correct URL (http://..../geoserver/web) directly into the browser

Answer (score 1):

Found that the setting in web.xml overrides the setting put in the Admin gui. So I just got it sorted by putting the new DNS proxy parms in the web.xml instead and everything worked again. :)